# Access denied while Accessing Sharepoint 2013 using WCF Web Service (Server Object model)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Access denied error occur while Accessing the Sharepoint List using Server side object mode from Custom Asp.NET WCF Web Service.

I have tried following option but no luck

1. With or without Impersonation using **SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges**
2. Added Identity tag with User(having Site collection admin rights) in web.cofig

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: The web.config notice made me wonder... Is this one a SharePoint hosted service you added in the ISAPI folder or something else?